# Custom python function will not recognize defined variables

Tags: python, function, spatial, arcpy

I am new to writing functions (using IDLE as my IDE of choice), and I am trying to write a function that will take a LANDSAT 8 satellite image and calculate an NDVI image. If you're unfamiliar with the LANDSAT 8 satellite, it collects multiple bands that can be combined into indices such as NDVI. The function is shown below, and is saved as ndviCalc2.py:

```
def ndvi(var1, var2):
    var1 = floatNir
    var2 = floatRed
    num = Minus(floatNir, floatRed)
    denom = Plus(floatNir, floatRed)
    ndvi = Divide(num, denom)
```

I am attempting to call the function in the following script:

```
#Import required python modules
import arcpy
import sys

#Update directory to import custom python modules, where the calcNdvi2.py file is saved
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Documents")

#Import custom function
import ndviCalc2

#Import classes: env specifies the workspace environment, and arcpy.sa specifies an extension that must be activated to run the script
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Check out spatial extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#Set environments
env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\toolData"
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Define local parameters, including different bands from the satellite image
input = "LANDSAT8_20150609.tif"
nir = input + "\\Band_5"
red = input + "\\Band_4"

#Convert parameters to floatin point rasters for calculation
floatNir = Float(nir)
floatRed = Float(red)

#Use custom script to calculate NDVI
#Calling the custom function here, and error occurs here:
ndvi = ndviCalc2.ndvi(floatNir, floatRed)

#Save raster to the workspace
ndvi.save(env.workspace + "\\ndvi_image.tif")

#Check spatial extension back in
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    ndvi = calcNdvi_correct.ndvi(floatNir, floatRed)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\ndviCalc2.py", line 11, in ndvi
    var1 = floatNir
NameError: global name 'floatNir' is not defined
```

How can I rewrite and properly call my function to get it to execute properly?

Comment: also the first two lines of your function should be removed

Comment: This issue is not related to the editor/ide used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def ndvi(floatNir, floatRed):
    num = Minus(floatNir, floatRed)
    denom = Plus(floatNir, floatRed)
    ndvi = Divide(num, denom)
```

This should be your function definition. If you are passing in floatNir and floatRed, there is no need use other vars.